# Raising a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, csv, exception, filenotfoundexception

I have a function that takes a source file containing times (a csv file), reads it, then sorts the lines in order and writes them in a destination file. However, if the source csv file does not exist, I need to raise a FileNotFoundError. I've raised exceptions before, for example, if a parameter wasn't an integer I had to raise ChangeParameterError by using:

```
class ChangeParameterError(Exception):
    pass
```

and then raising that in my function.

For my problem, my function is as follows:

```
def times(src,dst):
    s = open(src,'r')
    d = open(dst,'w')
    lines = s.readlines()
    s.close()
    lines.sort()
    for i in lines:
        print((str(i).strip()), file = d)
    d.close()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you try so far?  What did not work?

Comment: In python3, if you try to open a file that doesn't exist, the call to `open` will automatically throw a `FileNotFoundError` for you. In python2.7, it throws an `IOError`, but the idea is the same. What python version are you running, and do you specifically need the former error?

Comment: I have python 3.5.1, and the question specifically states to raise that error, but I do realize that even if I don't put any exception, that error shows up anyway

Comment: @A.M. so, I think you're actually all set with the code you provided in the question; you don't need to do anything. The calls to `open` are already set to throw the `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: @A.M. Test it by passing a filename that doesn't exist to src and see that infact the exception does get raised, then you can confirm what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

If the specified file is not found, the `FileNotFoundError` will be raised automatically by the `open` call when trying to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is automatically *raised* by python. But you may need to wrap your `open` with a `try-except` to *catch* the exception without breaking your code:

```
try:
    s = open(src,'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('file not found')
```